# Lots of Oops errors when clicking internal links

Tags: support

I'm getting lots of oops errors when clicking internal links (link from one question to another on AU)

[image: Oops error]

E.G. in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934679/swap-partition-to-swap-file) clicking the link for the duplicate [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904372/swap-partition-vs-swap-file) gives me an Oops reliably...

Is it me with my <s>anally retentive attitude towards privacy</s> "no cookies until explicitly allowed" policy or is it <s>Shog9</s> a Stack Exchange issue?

### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No I had it too on SO. Couldn't view some questions.

Comment: **Note to mods:** yes, [it made Shog9 smile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7335951#7335951)...

Answer (score 1):

## Urgh!

After being annoyed for 15 minutes by oops errors, *the moment I press "post"*, the problem [seems have to have disappeared](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47415463#47415463)!

<sub><sup>That's proof it was Shog9!  **;-)**</sup></sub>

Comment: **Note to mods:** yes, [it made Shog9 smile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7335951#7335951)...